# Android Hotspot - manage connected devices

Tags: root-access, wifi-hotspot

I use sometimes an old (rooted) Android 7 phone as a Hotspot for several other devices.
I have a data plan with 10 GB in a month, so not that much, so I need to know if some devices use more traffic than others.

In Android settings I can see how many connected devices my Hotspot has at the moment and their MAC-address. With `ip neigh` (in Termux or such) I can see the MAC and IP, so I can look on each device to check which is which.
This is very unhandy and I wonder why there is no (actual working) app to manage it.

The app should be able to block devices (as I can already in the Hotspot settings's) and great would be, if I could see the traffic used by each connected device.

Is there, in all those years, that Android Hotspot exists, really no app doing this?
I asked it in [xda-forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/android-hotspot-show-data-used-by-connected-devices.4349867/) years ago, without any answer.
Here in stackexchange I found nothing appropriate.

With root, this really should be possible I think, but how?

Comment: You didn't get an answer because you are looking for the wrong solution. Creating and managing hotspots is out of the scope of apps. It's a low level thing which has to be managed at operating system level. But Android doesn't provide that much control because, unlike a router, an Android phone is not meant to be a feature-rich access point device. On a rooted Android phone, however, you might be able to achieve what you want as you'd do on any Linux system. As a hint, see `macaddr_acl` in [hostapd.conf](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf).